# Is this a bug? Float operation being treated as integer

Tags: c#, asp.net

This operation returns a 0:

```
string value = “0.01”;
float convertedValue = float.Parse(value);
return (int)(convertedValue * 100.0f);
```

But this operation returns a 1:

```
string value = “0.01”;
float convertedValue = float.Parse(value) * 100.0f;
return (int)(convertedValue);
```

Because the convertedValue is a float, and it is in parenthesis *100f shouldn't it still be treated as float operation?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? I cannot reproduce this. I suspect it probably isn't happening as you describe, because indeed those two operations should return the same result.

Comment: It was in the code for an asp.net website. I believe it is configured to run .net 4 but not certain.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. I wish I could credit several of them.

Comment: The presence of a debugger is also very important, since that (by default) disables JIT optimizations.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you're running this program in 32bit mode.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference between the two lies in the way the compiler optimizes floating point operations. Let me explain.

```
string value = "0.01";
float convertedValue = float.Parse(value);
return (int)(convertedValue * 100.0f);
```

In this example, the value is parsed into an 80-bit floating point number for use in the inner floating point dungeons of the computer. Then this is converted to a 32-bit float for storage in the `convertedValue` variable. This causes the value to be rounded to, seemingly, a number slightly less than 0.01. Then it is converted back to an 80-bit float and multiplied by 100, increasing the rounding error 100-fold. Then it is converted to an 32-bit int. This causes the float to be truncated, and since it is actually slightly less than 1, the int conversion returns 0.

```
string value = "0.01";
float convertedValue = float.Parse(value) * 100.0f;
return (int)(convertedValue);
```

In this example, the value is parsed into an 80-bit floating point number again. It is then multiplied by 100, before it is converted to a 32-bit float. This means that the rounding error is so small that when it is converted to a 32-bit float for storage in `convertedValue`, it rounds to exactly 1. Then when it is converted to an int, you get 1.

The main idea is that the computer uses high-precision floats for calculations, and then rounds the values whenever they are stored in a variable. The more assignments you have with floats, the more the rounding errors accumulate.

Comment: "Then this is converted to a 32-bit float for storage in the convertedValue variable. " I don't believe this is guaranteed to happen. It might(especially without optimizations) be compiled like that sometimes, but the compiler is free to treat keep the value at 80 bits. If you read the CLI spec, storage in a local variable does not force a precision reduction.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You are correct. In this case, the optimization apparently did not happen, likely because it was a debug build. If the optimization did happen, the two pieces of code would be effectively identical.

Comment: This is an exemplary answer; I would just echo CodeInChaos's point that the C# and JIT compilers are permitted to make or not make this optimization *utterly at their whim*, and that it basically comes down to the details of register scheduling. CodeInChaos also notes correctly that casting to float disables the optimization.

Answer (score 14):

Please read an introduction to floatingpoint. This is a typical floating point problem. Binary floating points can't represent `0.01` exactly.

`0.01 * 100` is approximately 1.

If it happens to be rounded to `0.999...` you get `0`, and if it gets rounded to `1.000...` you get 1. Which one of those you get is undefined.

The jit compiler is not required to round the same way every time it encounters a similar expression(or even the same expression in different contexts). In particular it can use higher precision whenever it wants to, but can downgrade to 32 bit floats if it thinks that's a good idea.

---

One interesting point is an explicit cast to `float` (even if you already have an expression of type `float`). This forces the JITer to reduce the precision to 32 bit floats at that point. The exact rounding is still undefined though.

Since the rounding is undefined, it can vary between .net versions, debug/release builds, the presence of debuggers (and possibly the phase of the moon :P).

> Storage locations for floating-point numbers (statics, array elements, and fields of classes) are of fixed size. The 
>   supported storage sizes are float32 and float64. Everywhere else (**on the evaluation stack**, as arguments, as 
>   return types, and **as local variables**) floating-point numbers are represented using an internal floating-point 
>   type.
>
> When a floating-point value whose internal representation has greater range and/or precision than its nominal type is put in a storage location, it is automatically coerced to the type of the storage location.  This can involve 
>   a loss of precision or the creation of an out-of-range value (NaN, +infinity, or -infinity). **However, the value might be retained in the internal representation for future use, if it is reloaded from the storage location without 
>   having been modified.**  It is the responsibility of the compiler to ensure that the retained value is still valid at the time of a subsequent load, taking into account the effects of aliasing and other execution threads (see memory model  (§12.6)).  This freedom to carry extra precision is not permitted, however, following the execution of an explicit conversion (conv.r4 or conv.r8), at which time the internal representation must be 
>   exactly representable in the associated type.

---

Your specific problem can be solved by using `Decimal`, but similar problems with `3*(1/3f)` won't be solved by this, since `Decimal` can't represent one third exactly either.

Comment: You should emphasize the fact that this is *not* a bug.

Comment: Okay, I understand that float can have rounding errors, but why would it round differently in the first block from the second?

Comment: @user1270287 because it can. The jit-compiler is free to use higher precision if it wants, but it is not required to. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @spender I was too lazy to fish out the duplicate questions. Some people are allergic to that.

Comment: I downvoted you; you haven't linked to a suitable introduction to floating point, and I also think you are wrong - it doesn't sound reasonable that the statements above should result in a differen answer "because it can". That is not an appropriate answer.

Comment: @NoonSilk In the context of undefined behavior that's pretty much the only answer you can get.

Comment: @NoonSilk: This answer is in no way whatsoever wrong. Downvoting a perfectly good answer because **the person who is taking time out of their busy day to help you did not provide a link for people too lazy to type keywords into a search engine** is a poor way to thank someone for trying to add value.

Comment: @EricLippert: Why do you choose to misinterpret my comment? It makes discussion with you kind of ... "not fruitful". I simply provided a reason for my downvote - namely that I didn't think it was helpful. It can be improved by becoming more helpful, with more clarity. Isn't that what it's about? Should we not seek to improve the answers provided? (And the answer was wrong, I think, as it was trying to claim the behaviour was non-deterministic).

Comment: @Noon the behavior *is* allowed to be non deterministic, that's the whole point of undefined, rabbits may be pulled from hats and the length of their ears used to determine the precision of the internal calculations. Down voting for not providing a link is just lame.

Comment: CodeInChaos, "the exact rounding is undefined" is incorrect.  The result of the rounding depends on the precision, which is undefined, but the division operation and rounding are precisely defined.  Therefore, with a given precision, the result of `1 / 100` is also precisely defined.  (And because that's a fairly small quibble, *I did not vote down.*)

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
(int)(convertedValue * 100.0f)
```

The intermediate value is actually of higher precision, not simply a float. To obtain identical results to the second one, you'd have to do:

```
(int)((float)(convertedValue * 100.0f))
```

On the IL level, the difference looks like:

```
    mul 
    conv.i4
```

versus your second version:

```
    mul 
    stloc.3 
    ldloc.3 
    conv.i4
```

Note that the second one store/restores the value in a `float32` variable, which forces it to be of `float` precision. (Note that, as per CodeInChaos' comment, this is not guaranteed by the spec.)

(For completeness the explicit cast looks like:)

```
    mul 
    conv.r4 
    conv.i4
```

Comment: The intermediate value is a `float` as far as C# is concerned. And as far as the CLR is concerned, it can use any precision that is equal or higher than `float`. Often that's a 80bit float. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: Does a store/load force it to `float`? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I'm *assuming* it is working the same as in C - i.e. if you don't force stores/loads (e.g. with `-ffloat-store`) you get excess precision. I'll try to see if this is documented.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: (of course storing it forces it to be `float` here since `locals[3]` is `float32`. What I'm looking for is whether allowing excess precision is expressly allowed somewhere.)

Comment: my interpretation of the spec(see edit to my post) is that stloc+ldloc does not force a reduction in precision.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: interesting. So this behaviour is not guaranteed unless you use an explicit cast! This means that the second example really needs have the bizarre code `float convertedValue = (float)(float.Parse(value) * 100.0f);` to be *guaranteed* to be reduced in precision.

Answer (score -1):

I know this issue and alwayes working with it.
As our friend CodeInChaose answer that the floating point will not be presented on memory as its.

But i want to add that you have a reason for the different result, not because the JIT free to use the precision that he want.

The reason is on your first code you did convert the string and save it on memory so on this case its will not be saved 0.1 and some how will be saved 0.0999966 or something like this number.

On your second code you make the conversion and before you save it on memory and before the value is allocated on memory you did the multiplication operation so you will have your correct result without taking the risk of JIT precision of float numbers.

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is valid, at least when optimization is on.

Comment: Iam working on 4 languages (.Net , C++, JAVA , ObjectiveC ) all have the same result. if the value allocated on the memory variable then your end result is unexpected, and if you do the math operation * or / then assign the value to allocated variable you will have the correct result...

Comment: Assignment to a local variable is not guaranteed to have any effect on .net. A local variable is not a storage-location. And if it were a storage-location the compiler is free to keep the higher precision, if it can guarantee that the storage-location is read back unchanged. If you have contradicting information, please cite your sources(the spec). | C++ by itself does not guarantee anything regarding floating point rounding. With most compilers it depends on the flags you set. | No idea about JAVA and ObjectiveC.

Comment: On assignment to local veritable we can't expect the returned value if its correct or not,, what i said to solve this problem without any unexpected return value is to make your operation * , / , + , - on assignment.. if you read my answer again you will understand what i mean.. thanks